# How to retain overriding on character styles in a paragraph style - Ms Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

There is a paragraph style named prg and it has bold style. Inside a paragraph styled with prg there is a caharacter style named char and it hasn't bold style, but the prg style overriding it and char styled text looks bold. How to retain the char from general paragraph formattings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In Word, **Bold** is a *toggle* setting.

So, if your character style is set to Bold, it will actually turn off bold in the underlying paragraph style. You could create a separate character style that is set as Bold and when you apply it in a paragraph already Bold, it will toggle the Bold off.

I agree that it is confusing. Toggle means that if the feature is turned on and you tell it to turn on, it turns off. Both **Bold** and *Italics* work this way in Word. There is not really a Bold command, the command works as a "change Bold setting" command.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it's a little confusing, what's toggle setting, a bolded style should be bold necessarily as the name implies. There's another parser to read word paras and the style names important for me so if there's a bolded style it should look bold.

Comment: I agree that it is confusing. Toggle means that if the feature is turned on and you tell it to turn on, it turns off. Both **Bold** and *Italics* work this way in Word. There is not really a Bold command, the command works as a "change Bold setting" command.